# how to add a button in row of listview whenever particular row is selected?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to add a button in row of List whenever  row is selected first time and remove it when that row selected second time

thanks

Comment: add some code which you have tried..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your getview function of customListAdapter inflate a layout in which keep visibility of button as GONE,then onclick of listitem change the visibility of that button to VISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

in your row xml, add a Button and set visibility to View.GONE.
Inplement a clickListener on that row that will toggle visibility between View.VISIBLE and  View.GONE